# How do I the column above a hline

Tags: emacs, org-mode

```
       |---+-----+------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----+--------+------------+----------+-------|
       |   | Day |       Date | Star of day           | End of day            | Lunch | Sum of day | Float time | MyTime |       |
       | / |   < |          > | <                     |                       | >   |        |          < |        > |       |
       |---+-----+------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----+--------+------------+----------+-------|
       | ! | Dag |       Date | Start                 | End                   | Lunch | SOD    |  floatTime |    myTime |  Week |
       | / |     |            |                       |                       | <3> | <6>    |            |      <8> |       |
       | # |   1 | 2012-03-01 | <2012-03-01 to 08:20> | <2012-03-01 to 17:15> | 42  | 08:13  |    29580.0 |    8.217 | 16:49 |
       | # |   2 | 2012-03-02 | <2012-03-22 to 10:00> | <2012-03-22 to 14:00> | 42  | 03:18  |    11880.0 |    3.300 | 16:49 |
       | # |   3 | 2012-03-03 | <2012-03-22 to 08:00> | <2012-03-22 to 14:00> | 42  | 05:18  |    19080.0 |    5.300 | 16:49 |
       |---+-----+------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----+--------+------------+----------+-------|
       |   |     |            |                       |                       |     | Sum    |      16:49 |   16.817 | 11:31 |
```

I have the following table, which is using the formulas:

```
# Column Formulas
$7 = '(format-seconds "%.2h:%.2m" (- (- (float-time (org-time-string-to-time $End)) (float-time (org-time-string-to-time $Start))) (* (string-to-number $Lunch) 60)))
$8 = '(number-to-string (- (- (float-time (org-time-string-to-time $End)) (float-time (org-time-string-to-time $Start))) (* (string-to-number $Lunch) 60)))
$9 = '(/ (string-to-number (format-seconds "%m" $floatTime)) 60.0);%.3fN
$10 = '(format-seconds "%.2h:%.2m" (+ @-I$8..@+I$8));N

# Named Field Formulas
$LR10 = $LR8
$LR7 = Sum
$LR8 = '(format-seconds "%.2h:%.2m" (+ @2..));N
$LR9 = '(+ @2..@-I);N
```

The problem that i have is of $10, I would like to only show the calculated sum for the current week just above the hline, not on every column for the week?

---

Sorry, it might have been a bit unclear what i wanted. I'll try to do a mockup to explain my problem:

```
|--------+-------|
| Number | prob  |
|--------+-------|
|   25.0 |       |
|   50.0 |       |
|   30.0 |       |
|   10.0 | 115.0 |
|--------+-------|
|   10.0 |       |
|   20.0 |  30.0 |
|--------+-------|
|   145. |       |
```

this is the table that i have. the $LR1 = vsum(@2..@-I)
the problem that i have is to calculate the values in $2 just before the hline.
Which is the sum of the field in between the hlines.. Meaning 30.0 and 115.0..
How do I do that?

Basically @+I$2 (though this doesn't work for me..

Comment: Do you think you could provide a mockup of which cell you want to have the sum?  It will likely be done using a cell formula rather than a column formula, but I'm not sure which cell you'd want to associate it to.

Comment: It would also be useful to show the entire `#+table` code to get a better feeling of how to help.

Comment: The title is missing a verb.  Is it *sum*?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, although it requires a slightly creative formula to work.  (It should work more easily but for some reason the obvious cell reference fails).

Using your example table the formulas required are below (note that I split the formula line in the middle of the `::`'s that separate the formulas to avoid wrapping.

```
|--------+------|
| Number | prob |
|--------+------|
|     25 |      |
|     50 |      |
|     30 |      |
|     10 |  115 |
|--------+------|
|   10.0 |      |
|   20.0 |  30. |
|--------+------|
|   145. | 145. |
|--------+------|
#+TBLFM: @IIIII-1$2..@IIIII$2=vsum(@IIII$1..@IIIII$1):
:@IIII-1$2..@IIII$2=vsum(@III$1..@IIII$1):
:@III-1$2..@III$2=vsum(@II$1..@III$1)
```

So for any area between two horizontal lines you have to set the desired line as: `@II-1$2..@II$2`, or in the case of your original example it would be `@II-1$10@II$10`

The `@I-1` form only seems to work in range formulas, even though it should only specify a single row.  So you have to use the range of `@I-1..@I` for it to only select the single desired row (And then specify which column)